# What is the most elegant way in Ruby to remove a parameter from a URL?

Tags: ruby, url, parsing

I would like to take out a parameter from a URL by its name without knowing which parameter it is, and reassemble the URL again.

I guess it is not that hard to write something on my own using CGI or URI, but I imagine such functionality exists already. Any suggestions?

In:

```
http://example.com/path?param1=one&param2=2&param3=something3
```

Out:

```
http://example.com/path?param2=2&param3=something3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *addressable* gem will do this nicely; please see the superior answer by *The Tin Man*.  But if you want to roll your own, here's how.  The only claim this code has to elegance is that it hides the ugly in a method:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

def reject_param(url, param_to_reject)
  # Regex from RFC3986
  url_regex = %r"^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$"
  raise "Not a url: #{url}" unless url =~ url_regex
  scheme_plus_punctuation = $1
  authority_with_punctuation = $3
  path = $5
  query = $7
  fragment = $9
  query = query.split('&').reject do |param|
    param_name = param.split(/[=;]/).first
    param_name == param_to_reject
  end.join('&')
  [scheme_plus_punctuation, authority_with_punctuation, path, '?', query, fragment].join
end   

url = "http://example.com/path?param1=one&param2=2&param3=something3"
p url
p reject_param(url, 'param2')

# => "http://example.com/path?param1=one&param2=2&param3=something3"
# => "http://example.com/path?param1=one&param3=something3"
```

Comment: Upvote for using the actual regex from the RFC. Excellent reference.

Comment: Semicolons can also be used to separate the query parameters, your `reject_param` doesn't work with this valid URL `http://example.com/path?param1=one;param2=2;param3=something3`.

Comment: @mu is too short, Thanks.  I've amended (but not tested) the code to allow for `;` as well as `=`.

Answer (score 41):

I prefer to use:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://example.com/path?param1=one&param2=2&param3=something3')

params = uri.query_values #=> {"param1"=>"one", "param2"=>"2", "param3"=>"something3"}
params.delete('param1') #=> "one"
uri.query_values = params #=> {"param2"=>"2", "param3"=>"something3"}

uri.to_s #=> "http://example.com/path?param2=2&param3=something3"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Github page for addressable: https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/tree/

Comment: This is _so_ much nicer than my solution.

Comment: If params is empty than this results in an unnecessary "?" at the end of the url.  In Rails I simply added ".presence" to turn the empty hash into nil which prevented the extra "?".     So "uri.query_values = params.presence"

Answer (score 30):

Maybe a little off-topic, but for anyone who's attempting to do this in the context of a rails app you can simply do:

```
url_for(params.except(:name_of_param_to_delete))
```

N.B. Tested in rails v2.3.9.

Comment: and the opposite of `except` is `slice`

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to include an extra Gem and if you don't want nasty Regex, here's my prefered way:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'uri'

url = "http://example.com/path?param1=one&param2=2&param3=something3"

uri = URI(url) #=> #<URI::HTTP:0x007fbe25141a78 URL:http://example.com/path?param1=one&param2=2&param3=something3>
params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(uri.query || "") #=> {"param1"=>["one"], "param2"=>["2"], "param3"=>["something3"]}
params.delete('param1') #=> ["one"]
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params) #=> "param2=2&param3=something3"

uri.to_s #=> "http://example.com/path?param2=2&param3=something3"
```

**Note,** choose wisely:

```
CGI.parse('a=b&a=c') #=> {"a"=>["b", "c"]}
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query('a=b&a=c') #=> {"a"=>"c"}
```

And:

```
URI.encode_www_form({ a: :b, c: { d: 2 }}) #=> "a=b&c=%7B%3Ad%3D%3E2%7D"
{ a: :b, c: { d: 2 }}.to_query #=> "a=b&c%5Bd%5D=2"
```

Comment: I would modify the CGI parse like so to handle missing params...  `CGI.parse(uri.query || "")` otherwise the parse raises an exception.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with something like this

```
 def uri_remove_param(uri, params = nil)
   return uri unless params
   params = Array(params)
   uri_parsed = URI.parse(uri)
   return uri unless uri_parsed.query
   escaped = uri_parsed.query.grep(/&amp;/).size > 0
   new_params = uri_parsed.query.gsub(/&amp;/, '&').split('&').reject { |q| params.include?(q.split('=').first) }
   uri = uri.split('?').first
   amp = escaped ? '&amp;' : '&'
   "#{uri}?#{new_params.join(amp)}"
 end
```

Comment: Give yourself the checkmark; I like your answer better.  URI.parse?  Yet another handy library I knew nothing about.  Oh, your params = [params] if... line?  You can replace that with params = Array(params).  I learned that trick on SO, of course.

Comment: actually after playing with Array(params) for a while... Array({}) should be used with caution because it also converts hash to array.

Answer (score 4):

One line should be enough:

```
url.sub(/\?param_to_remove=[^&]*/, '?').sub(/\&param_to_remove=[^&]*/, '').sub(/\?$/,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clean one if your url is a string:

```
  def remove_param(url, param_name)
    uri = URI(url)
    params = []
    URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || '').each do |param|
      next if param[0] == param_name

      params << param
    end
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    uri.to_s
  end
```

note: you could use this to remove a param with a specific value by changing:

```
def remove_param(url, param_value)
```

and

```
next if param[1] == param_value
```