# How to remove a part of string?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am new to Ruby and currently I am trying to take out a part from the http request string.

Request :
`POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&name=John&address=UK`

Is there any way to take out `"name=John&"` using `slice`, `gsub` or any other method ? 
Output should be `POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&address=UK`

Note : The value of "name" parameter can be different every time

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ...

```
str = "POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&name=John&address=UK"
str = str.sub(/&name=.+&/, '&')
str
=> "POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&address=UK"
```

Comment: This fails if the name parameter does not come between two other parameters. What if it gets reordered to be first or last?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable). That's probably easier than writing some string modification solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` on the string to turn it into an array, then `reject` the `name=` element, then `join` them into a string:

```
"POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&name=John&address=UK".split('&').reject { |e| e.start_with?('name=') }.join('&')
=> "POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&address=UK"
```

There are additional possibilities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149639/3784008).

Answer (score 0):

It's not the short answer, but it's probably the most robust since it actually parses the URL

```
require 'uri'

# parse
request = "POST /test/userRegistration?id=1234&name=John&address=UK".split
uri = URI request[1]
query = URI.decode_www_form uri.query
# modify the query params
query.delete_if { |param| param[0] == "name" }
# convert back to string
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form query
new_request = "#{request[0]} #{uri}"
```